# How did Chris Hemsworth train for Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, avengers-endgame

Of course, I'm refering to

> Fat Thor

Now obviously this involved a

> prosthetic beer belly, but

**How did Chris Hemsworth modify his training regimen and diet for this movie compared to his previous appearances?**

> Did he intentionally reduce or skip his workout regimen?   Did he intentionally consume additional or unhealthy foods?

Comment: ? If that's CGI or padding, why does he need to modify his diet?

Comment: @Jenayah:   (1) being too muscular (arms) shows through (2) face weight (3) why train/diet hard if you don't need to?

Comment: 1/ if they can animate a walking tree they can thin his muscles 2/ see previous point 3/ 'cause you like it? Lots of people train because they like it, to be healthier, fitter, for looks...

Comment: @Jenayah:   Why are we debating this?   (1) they can but it's expensive  (3) the question doesn't presuppose whether he like it or not.   It just asks if he modified his training regimen.     In particular, some actors go to extreme lengths for certain roles.  In this case, if he does train for the reasons you give, then it puts him in a quandary.   Hence why the question is interesting.

Comment: Dunno. That started out as an​ "on the spot" comment and we circled back after that. We can probably leave it as is, don't hesitate to flag as NLN when read. Cheers :)

Comment: This seems to me off topic for SFF.

Comment: @JunKang - "*What topics can I ask about here? Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is for questions targeted towards science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. This includes questions about: **Behind-the-scenes and fandom information**"*; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JunKang what Valorum said, but just to clarify, fandom questions are OK as long as they somewhat relate to a work/franchise, which is the case here. Asking "Does [actor from sci-fi movie] like [whatever food]" would clearly have been off-topic.

Comment: @Jenayah Is an actor's workout routine/diet really behind-the-scenes or fandom? Would "what kind of camera was used to film X?" be considered on topic here because it's kinda "behind-the-scenes?" I would argue neither seem to be on topic. And "as long as they somewhat relate to a work/franchise" is an argument that can be made for pretty much anything. But I suppose that's just my opinion since its kinda (imho unclearly) defined in the SE on-topic page.

Comment: @JunKang as it's an adaptation of a comicbook character and the process that went behind it, namely the physical preparation, it's on-topic (whether it's _interesting_ is up to readers and the voting buttons). The camera example is a bit vague to give a clear-cut yes/no answer (it'd probably be off-topic if left that vague, but might be on-topic if more info is given on how that's relevant). If I'm not being very clear (it's a bit late), I'm happy to discuss that further but I suggest we do so in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/) so that we don't annoy OP with comments notifs

Comment: I thought my answer to this one was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd want me to address before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 6):

Apparently his training regime for Endgame was different from his previous roles as Thor.

> Luke said that workouts ahead of filming the latest movie were
> different to Chris' normal regime, as they would normally use lighter
> weights and focus more on quick-paced circuit-style training.
>
> 'Workouts for Endgame were generally no longer than an hour, targeting
> two muscle groups per session,' he outlined. 'We limited the movements
> to four exercises per muscle group with heavy weights, and around six
> to 12 repetitions.'
>
> Luke said that 'it's not about working out more,' but simply 'working
> smarter'.
>
> 'There are three sessions we stuck to,' he explained. 'Sometimes
> doubling up the sessions in one week, but never exceeding six days of
> exercise a week.'
>
> <sub><sup>[EXCLUSIVE 'It's about working smarter, not harder': Chris Hemsworth's trainer Luke Zocchi on how the star gets into superhero shape ahead of Avengers: Endgame release](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-6941721/Luke-Zocchi-training-Chris-Hemsworth-Avengers-Endgame.html)</sup></sub>

As to what he was *eating*, the emphasis was on a high protein diet with a greater *mix* of foods and a stronger emphasis on 'wholefoods' to give him the calories needed for his daily workout regime and protein to help him to maintain muscle mass.

> Chris complemented his training regime with a diet of 'mostly wholefoods rich in nutrients using various types of proteins, grains, fruits, legumes and fats.'
>
> The father-of-three's chef and Centr's food expert, Sergio Perera,
> told Daily Mail Australia that Chris gained and maintained muscle by
> adding red meat and more complex grains such as steamed rice, barley,
> wholegrain pastas and hearty breads.
>
> 'He'd usually consume these during workout days [and keep them to a
> minimum at night],' he explained.
>
> 'It can be quite a challenge sometimes to keep consuming so many
> calories, so he'd add extra snacks of two to three green shakes,
> containing vegetables, fats and plant-based proteins.'

Since achieving the "*fat thor look*" was mostly the work of prosthetics and CGI, his workout was largely (it seems) focused on building up his upper body and arms.

---

Note that Hemsworth was, during the filming of Endgame, still filming 'pickup' scenes for Infinity War, so *actually* bulking up to play the role would have been impossible.

> "We had to toggle back and forth," Anthony Russo told "While we were
> shooting 'Endgame' where he was heavier we had to do some pickup shots
> for 'Infinity War,' so he would have to go back and forth between
> those two looks. So he had to wear a bodysuit, and it was quite heavy.
> That suit started to wear on his back, which was scary when you have
> someone who has to be so physical."
>
> <sub><sup>['Avengers: Endgame' directors describe the 100-hour workweeks and tremendous pressure of making their $2 billion blockbuster](https://www.businessinsider.com/avengers-endgame-directors-describe-making-of-the-movie-interview-2019-5?_ga=2.56393195.1594069129.1558119210-1152507828.1558119210&r=US&IR=T)</sup></sub>

Comment: Wasn't he also working on Men In Black:International as well?

Comment: @CBredlow - I've no idea whether he gets his kit off in that. Presumably he does.